# I'm having a problem selecting an element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I'm using [selectorgadget](http://www.selectorgadget.com/) to help me select elements on the document. But when I used it on jQuery it doesn't work. The nth-child selector seems not to work for me.

```
<div id = "wrap">
<div class = "book">
    <div class = "chapter">
        <p class = "text">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Title</td>
                        <td>
                            <b>jQuery</b>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        <p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The HTML is above. There are many book class. The div wrap is the wrapper that enclosed them all. Selector Gadget said that when I use:

`$("#wrap tr:nth-child(1) b")` It should select the TD element with the `<b>` tag in it. So it should select "jQuery".

I tried it, but it didn't work. When I tried:

```
var query = $("#wrap tr:nth-child(1) b").text();
alert(query);
```

The browser sends an alert with no text. And when I tried:

```
var query = $("#wrap tr:nth-child(1) b").html();
alert(query);
```

The browser sends a NULL alert.

What's wrong?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to include the Markup.. Sorry! Thanks

Comment: I just tried your code and it worked fine for me...

Answer (score 2):

I've tried this with FF 3.0.10, jQuery 1.3.2, greasemonkey 0.8.2

```
var query = $("#wrap tr:nth-child(2) b").text();
returns "jQuery"
```

the 2 in nth-child() does the trick!!
Index for nth-child starts from 1 not 0

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

modified, i first didnt notice the tr:nth-child, there is no 1 child tr in that table, but there is a td at index 1

```
var query = $(".text td:nth-child(1) b").html();
alert(query);
```

Comment: Yeah, it return null. Whenever I use the nth-child. I get the null everytime.

I'm using greasemonkey with jQuery. Perhaps I can't use nth-child in greasemonkey?

Comment: John I can use .text tr b. But I want to know why I can't use the nth-child. Because I need to select other more complicated elements in the document that requires the use of nth-child.

Comment: I tried it also, still no luck.. Is there any alternative to nth-child?

Comment: The nth child is the problem I think. Everytime I use nth child it always returns null.

Answer (score 0):

In testing your sample in Firefox 3 and IE8, I was able to get back the text you expected using your selector after one tweak - I added an ID of "wrap" to your table element:

```
<table id="wrap">
```

Once that was added in, your selector seemed to work just fine. Is there a particular platform you are having trouble with?

Comment: I'm using Greasemonkey. It is not my HTML document.. Maybe I need to add a class to all the table?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your example code and it worked straight away. What version of jQuery are you using? It works in 1.3.2

Here's the working example: http://jsbin.com/uzuzu/edit

Comment: I'm using 1.3.2.

Hmm, I think the problem is in Greasemonkey.. I'm using Greasemonkey with jQuery.

Comment: how are you referencing jQuery? are you using unsafeWindow.jQuery ?

Answer (score 0):

You need nth-child(2), :nth-child(1) picks out title.  Remember that :eq is 0-based, while :nth-child() is 1-based.  Confusing!